# $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers, is there a subsequence $\{b_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ s.t. $b_{n+1}/b_n \to 0,1$ or $ \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers.

Then does there exist a subsequence $\{a_{k_n}\}_{n\ge 1}$ of $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ such that either $\{\dfrac {a_{k_{n+1}}}{a_{k_n}}\}_{n\ge 1}$ converges to $1$ or $0$ or $\{\dfrac {a_{k_{n}}}{a_{k_{n+1}}}\}_{n\ge 1}$ converges to $0$ ?

Comment: Any restrictions on the sequence?  How about, $a_n = 1$?

Comment: @badjohn "converges to **1** or $0$"

Comment: @GabrielRomon Question may be a little ambiguous.  I thought that the OP wanted to find multiple subsequences.  One which converged to $0$, one to $1$, and one to $\infty$.  I see now that it can be read differently and be more interesting.

Comment: Hint: Either the sequence $(a_n)$ has a finite nonzero limit point, and then ..., or the sequence $(a_n)$ has no finite nonzero limit point, and then ...

Comment: Note that $b_n/b_{n+1}\to 0$ is weaker than $b_{n+1}/b_n\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may assume that all $a_k$ are positive. If only finitely many $a_k$ are positive, we consider the sequence $\{-a_k\}_k$ instead.

If the sequence converges to a non-zero limit, we clearly find a subsequence such that the quotient converges to $1$.
More generally, the same is true if the sequence has a non-zero accumulation point.

If the sequence converges to $0$ (or again more generally: if $0$ is an accumulation point), we easily find a subsequence such that the quotient converges to $0$. Just Pick $n_1=1$ and recursively $n_{k+1}=\min\{\,i\in\Bbb N\mid i>n_k, 0<a_i<\frac1ka_{n_k}\,\}$.

Remains the case that the sequence has no accumulation point at all. But then it is unbounded and $0$ is an accumulation point of $\frac1{a_n}$. A subsequence of this with limit quotient $0$ corresponds to a limit quotient $+\infty$ of the original sequence.